# Do you write plus/minus if a variable squares equals the square root of a number?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, inequality, square-numbers

For example, if I have $x^2 = \sqrt{49}$. I know that $7$ is the number, but as my final answer, do I write that $x = +\sqrt{7}$ and $-\sqrt{7}$ or just $x = \sqrt{7}$?

Comment: $x^2=49$ or $x^2=\sqrt{49}$?

Comment: Solution for the equation as stated above is $x=\pm\sqrt7$.

Answer (score 1):

For any $a>0$, if you have an equation $x^{2}=a$, then note that both $(\sqrt{a})^{2}=a$ and $(-\sqrt{a})^{2}=a$. Thus, both $a$ and $-a$ are solutions, and hence, they must both be considered. In your case, you have $x^{2}=\sqrt{49}=7$. Therefore, both $x=\sqrt{7}$ and $x=-\sqrt{7}$ satisfy this equation.

Comment: If $x^2=7$, then how is $x=\pm 7$ the solution?

Comment: Obviously a typo. Fixed.

Comment: When I graph x = 7 into an equation, I don't get the same graph that I get when I graph -7.

Comment: That's because they are two different graphs. Both, however, are solutions to the problem.

Comment: I need the graph to pass through a specific point though, so how do I know which one?

Comment: Can you explain further? Which point does it have to pass through?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x^2=7 \implies (x-\sqrt{7})(x+\sqrt{7})=0$.

Therefore, there are two roots, $x=\pm \sqrt{7}$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  If the answer is not useful, I am happy to delete.  Please advise.  -Mark

Answer (score -1):

**It depends on which field you expect/require the answer to be in:**

If the answer is allowed to be a *complex* number, then the equation $x^2 = \sqrt{49}$ can be rewritten as $x^2 = 7$ OR $x^2 = -7$, which collectively yield four values: $x = +\sqrt{7}$, $x = -\sqrt{7}$, $x = +i\sqrt{7}$, and $x = -i\sqrt{7}$.

If the answer is required to be a *real* number, then the equation $x^2 = \sqrt{49}$ can be rewritten as $x^2 = 7$ OR $x^2 = -7$, which, since $x^2 = -7$ has no real solution, yields only two values: $x = +\sqrt{7}$ and $x = -\sqrt{7}$.

If the answer is required to be a *rational* number, *or a number in an extension of the rationals which does not contain $\sqrt{7}$*, then of course there is no solution.

Comment: If you are interpreting $\sqrt{49}$ to be double-valued, then why do you distinguish between $+\sqrt{7}$ and $-\sqrt{7}$?  I think you are using $\sqrt{}$ inconsistently.

Comment: This answer lacks clarity and rigor.  Choose A branch for the square root function.